# Update SQL when where clause condition can be null

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement, ibatis

I have an update SQL statement to update a row

```
   UPDATE COM_TRANSACTION_LOGS    
        SET END_TIME  = ?, 
        RESPONSE   = ?  
   WHERE   
   TRANSACTION_ID  = ?   
   AND    
   MESSAGE_ID  = ?
```

The problem here is that the `MESSAGE_ID`  can be null in some cases so the update SQL comes as

```
  [DEBUG] {pstm-100101} Parameters:[2013-05-14 10:38:01.485, XML, 123XYZAAA1236511, null]
```

This fails to update because the where clause becomes like

```
WHERE   
   TRANSACTION_ID  = '123XYZAAA1236511'
   AND    
   MESSAGE_ID  = null
```

How can I compare against null value through prepared statement.

I know this where clause for null comparison has to be like this

```
   WHERE   
     TRANSACTION_ID  = '123XYZAAA1236511'
   AND    
      MESSAGE_ID  is null
```

How can I tell my prepared statement to set the where clause as `is null` without using two queries and using them conditionally in case of `null` or `='somevalue`

Comment: Just use two prepared statements, as long as you do not have an unbounded number of different statements, there should be no bgi problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace this line:

```
MESSAGE_ID  = ?
```

By this:

```
COALESCE(MESSAGE_ID,-1) = COALESCE(?,-1)
```

Answer (score 4):

In Oracle there is an [NVL](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php) statement for accomplishing this (`nvl(?, value_to_replace_null)`). I'm not sure what variant of SQL you're using, but there is probably something similar. You might also use [IFNULL, ISNULL, and COALESCE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) for SQL Server and MySQL.

Comment: nvl didn't worked. The log statement shows the update query as **UPDATE COM_TRANSACTION_LOGS    SET END_TIME  = ?,    RESPONSE   = ?   WHERE    MESSAGE_ID  =  NVL(? ,'is NULL')       AND    TRANSACTION_ID  = ?**

Comment: @NullPointerException - you would need to `nvl` both sides of the test so they get the same value, as Adrian has with `coalesce` (which is more portable). You need to be careful that the 'magic' value you choose can never exist in real data if you take either approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using NVL/NVL2 for your purpose. It gets the work done.